# Assign a task to a user

Tags: 8, entities

I have a batch function that is called when the user has submitted the webform.

Is there a function where I can assign the task to a specific user or role using a batch function?

```php
function maestro_hook_is_draft($processID, $queueID) {
  $sid = MaestroEngine::getEntityIdentiferByUniqueID($processID, 'submission');
  if ($sid) {
    $webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($sid);
    if ($webform_submission) {
      if ($webform_submission->isDraft()) {
        //if webform is draft, assign task to user
        /* NEED HELP HERE */
      }
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

The closest method Maestro uses to assign functions is `productionAssignments()` in MaestroEngine.php.

```php
/**
 * Using the queueID, the task's machine name and the template machine name, we assign the task 
 * using the appropriate method defined in the template.
 * 
 * @param string $templateMachineName  Machine name of the template
 * @param string $taskID Machine name of the task
 * @param int $queueID  The ID of the queue entity this task belongs to
 */
protected function productionAssignments($templateMachineName, $taskID, $queueID) {
  // ...
  $assignments = explode(',', $assigned);
  foreach($assignments as $assignment) {
    $thisAssignment = explode(':', $assignment);
    // [0] is user, role etc.
    // [1] is how such as fixed or by variable. 
    // [2] is to whom or which variable
      
    if ($thisAssignment[1] == 'fixed') { //assigned by fixed name
      $values = array (
        'queue_id' => $queueID,
        'assign_type' => $thisAssignment[0],
        'by_variable' => 0,
        'assign_id' => $thisAssignment[2],
        'process_variable' => 0,
        'assign_back_id' => 0,
        'task_completed' => 0,
      );
      $prodAssignments = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('maestro_production_assignments')->create($values);
      $prodAssignments->save();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In Maestro all you really need is the $processID because then you can get pretty much do everything - 
try to loaded it where you have /* NEED HELP HERE */

via  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('maestro_process')->load($processID); 
then you can get the template meta if you know that annd the $queueID you can guess at the next $queueID and then create the $prodAssignment  or can create your own task type because there just plugins 
see patch here https://www.drupal.org/project/maestro/issues/3067457
on how to make a custom task type